# How to close the app

Tags: android

I have created one android application....in my application the user press the home key on current activity or open activity , the application will be closed and if he open the activity again the launcher activity will be open ...i have done everything is right....

in my app total 7 activity's are there if the user press the home key on any activity the application is closed..but if he open the activity again the launcher activity also opened but in background previous activity is opened. 
how to solve this problem

one more question

if i press the home key on any activity the application will be closed and that will be there on recent app list.if i press on the recent app list the app must be open launcher activity....
how to do it ....

Comment: Your question is not clear dude, reframe it. Though some corner of my brain is saying that TmKVU's solution should work.

Comment: In my app total 7 activity's are there if i press home key on any activity the app will be closed..  android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"   i have written this code in my manifestfile on launcher activity,,if i open the app always open launcher activity, the launcher activity is opened but in background where we press the home key on activity ,the activity is open on background ....

Comment: So far, I have understood this: Your app has seven activities. When someone minimizes your app, you want the launcher or the main activity of your app to be launched when reopened, isn't it? Then what?

Comment: The launcher activity is opened but where ever we closed or minimizes the app,the activity is appear on the background.

Comment: You know what? It's really really hard to understand what are you saying. What other languages you do prefer? If it's Hindi you can ask me in that and I would edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I would like to say that, if I minimize the app on current opend activity, if I want to relaunch the activity again that would be open launcher activity properly but the problem is,launcher activity back where we had minimize the app on activity that activity had opend back side....